# Determine flavor of SQL being used

Tags: sql, database

I have a mysterious SQL database presented through a web interface. I tried to `show tables;` but was told that's not a valid command, so I'm trying to figure out what flavor of SQL this is.

Does anyone know a command that can help identify the flavor of SQL being used? Any pointers would be very helpful!

Comment: You sort of have to cycle through database-specific commands.  A good source for them is https://dbfiddle.uk/.  It has a default command for each database.

Comment: On windows if you have access have a look at what services are running.PS what makes you think the repository is SQL at all could it be isam files,flat files, spreadsheets...

Comment: this maybe a postgres database. Try `\l+`.

Comment: I know the interface accepts some SQL looking query syntax ("select ham from eggs where...". The `\l+` query throws `Incorrect syntax near '\'.` Querying for `select @@version;` throws `Access to variables is forbidden.` I'm happy to try other commands!

Comment: Could also be spss.

Comment: Try `select version();` or `select @@version` or `select * from v$version;`

Comment: If it'll run it, `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` might be informative since it'll show what the system thinks catalogs and schemas are, and what ones there are, and many SQL database systems support `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.

Comment: Of course, if the web interface is performing some query sanitisation before passing it through to the database system, that'll make it trickier.

Answer (score 6):

Not an answer but a comment that doesn't fit in the comments. You can start by trying the following commands and see if one succeeds:

- Oracle: `select * from V$VERSION;`
- DB2: `select service_level from sysibmadm.env_inst_info;`
- PostgreSQL: `select version();`
- SQL Server: `select @@version;`
- MariaDB: `select version();`
- MySQL: `select version();`
- H2: `SELECT H2VERSION() FROM DUAL`
- SQLite: `select sqlite_version();`
- Firebird: `select rdb$get_context('SYSTEM', 'ENGINE_VERSION') as version from rdb$database;`

HyperSQL gives itself away by implementing the `BOOLEAN` and `INTERVAL` types.

In Derby you can select from the table `sysibm.sysdummy1` (as well as in DB2).

Comment: I struck out with all of these, but I +1 this for all the options!